# jquery effect - Slide hidden div down / Up, hiding currently showed hidden div

Tags: jquery, button, effects, slidedown

*** Scenario

i wish to make a jquery effect like the one found on this website, which is sitting to the right of the main flash add:

http://www.commbank.com.au/

*** Problem

I have made a start, but have hit a little snag with muy method.. perhaps its not the best way to achieve my desired effect, please advise and thanks in advance!!

My Code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/HSbzC/1/

Also i will display it below:

*** HTML

```
<div id="latestNewsJs">              
    <div id="lnClickDivs1" class="sideJsBtns sidejsbtn1"></div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv1" class="secretDiv"></div>
    <div id="lnClickDivs2" class="sideJsBtns sidejsbtn2"></div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv2" class="secretDiv"></div>        
    <div id="lnClickDivs3" class="sideJsBtns sidejsbtn3"></div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv3" class="secretDiv"></div>
    <div id="lnClickDivs4" class="sideJsBtns sidejsbtn4"></div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv4" class="secretDiv"></div>
</div>
```

*** CSS

```
#latestNewsJs {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:106px;
    min-height:100%; 
}
#lnClickDivs1 {}
#lnClickDivs2 {}
#lnClickDivs3 {}
#lnClickDivs4 {}

.sideJsBtns {
    width:106px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#hiddenDiv1 {}
#hiddenDiv2 {}
#hiddenDiv3 {}
#hiddenDiv4 {}

.secretDiv {
    background:orange; 
    width:106px; 
    height:100px; 
    display:none; 
    margin-top:-7px;
    float:left;
}
```

*** jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){         

    var curI = 0;

    jQuery('.sideJsBtns').click(function(){

        curI = jQuery(this).index() + 1;

        jQuery(".secretDiv").slideUp("medium");

        if (jQuery("#hiddenDiv" + curI).is(":hidden")) 
        {
            jQuery("#hiddenDiv" + curI).slideDown("medium");
        } else {
            jQuery("#hiddenDiv" + curI).slideUp("medium");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: If you're referring to the part of the page I think you are, that's usually called an "accordion." [jQuery UI has one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `index()` method to get the element index. If you dont pass any selector to this method it will give the index relative to all its siblings.

Take a look at this fiddle I have fixed it

http://jsfiddle.net/HSbzC/2/

Comment: Perfect.. at least i was close and thanks for the explanation of where i was going wrong, much appreciated !! ;)

Comment: Hi... I would also like to stop any other divs animating while there is one currently animating...?? Also, if you click the div a few time in a row it will keep animating long after you click.. how can we stop this from happening..?? Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Or use this code without any **index()**

http://jsfiddle.net/HSbzC/3/